# Fixed horizontal alignment in list

Tags: horizontal-alignment, lists

I want to create a list like the one shown below:

> ```
> Date of Birth:       14 
> Contact address:     Alsaksa
> permanent address:   cbsdfhkjhsdlkf....
>                      fjdhkgjh
> languages known:     fjdkjflsdjfkjdghkdf
> Location preference: dfjsd
> ```

How can I make the description of each label continue from the same position like for the permanent address label? I am currently using the following code:

```
\resheading{\textbf{PERSONAL DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]
\begin{itemize}
\item Date of Birth:   14\textsuperscript{th} 
\item \noindent Permanent Address: bcbv
\end{itemize}
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) Please turn your code snippet into a complete [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3225/117050)! To be honest, I don't understand what you're asking at all. Please elaborate. Also your heading should be a heading and not the complete question. Please put the rest of your question in the text block.

Comment: try to use a tabular: `\begin{tabular}{ll} Date of Birth:  &    14\\ Contact address: &     Alsaksa\\ ... \end{tabular}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

let me elaborate my comment:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tabularx}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{}l X}
Date of birth:          &   14\textsuperscript{th}      \\
Contact address:        &   Alsaksa                     \\
Permanent address:      &   cbsdfhkjhsdlkf ... fjdhkgjh \\
Languages known:        &   fjdkjflsdjfkjdghkdf         \\
Location preference:    &   \lipsum*[11]
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i used your above syntax before that i wrote a command   \resheading{\textbf{PERSONAL DETAILS} }\\[\lsep]  it appear like the table is submerged into the heading...

Comment: i don't know any context of use table use. therefore i cant say anything without seeing an example of use. a guessing: try encapsulate table in `\begin{center} ... \end{center}`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with a `description` environment and `enumitem`:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem, calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[font=\normalfont, labelwidth=\widthof{Location preference:}, leftmargin=\widthof{Location preference:}+\labelsep]
    \item[Date of birth:] 14\textsuperscript{th}
    \item[Contact address:] Alsaksa
    \item[Permanent address:] cbsdfhkjhsdlkf.... fjdhkgjh cbsdfhkjhsdlkf.... fjdhkgjh fjdh kgjh cbsdfhkjhsdlkf....
    \item[Languages known:] fjdkjflsdjfkjdghkdf
    \item[Location preference:] dfjsd
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't `tabularx` be better in this case? Just because of the changing label width depending on the contents.

Comment: @Skillmon: It's a possibility. I preferred this one from a semantic point  of view. Anyway, with this solution you can choose a fixed (sufficiently large) value of `labelwidth`.